# MySQL Query Optimization for below Query

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization, amazon-aurora

Below are the Table Schema and Data in EVENT_DETAILS is 1.76 Million Records

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT_DETAILS
(
  ORG_ID CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  CONFIG_KEY CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  COMPONENT_NAME VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
  REQUEST_ID  CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  UPDATE_DATE INT NOT NULL,
  UPDATE_TIME INT NOT NULL,
  CLIENT CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  STATUS INT NOT NULL,
  EVENT_DATA VARCHAR(1024),
  MESSAGE VARCHAR(512),
  INSERTED_TIME     TIMESTAMP      DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX MYINDEX1 ON EVENT_DETAILS (ORG_ID,CONFIG_KEY,COMPONENT_NAME,UPDATE_DATE);
CREATE INDEX MYINDEX2 ON EVENT_DETAILS (UPDATE_DATE,COMPONENT_NAME);

CREATE TABLE DOMAIN_KEYS (
  DOMAIN_KEY char(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  DOMAIN_IDENTITY varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  DOMAIN_DISPLAY_NAME varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  ORG_ID char(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  LOCATION_KEY int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  DESCRIPTION varchar(4000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  CATEGORY int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  ENVIRONMENT_TYPE int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (DOMAIN_KEY)
);

CREATE TABLE ORGANISATIONS (
  ORG_ID char(32) NOT NULL,
  ORG_IDENTITY varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  ORG_NAME varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  ORG_DESC varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PARENT_ORG_ID char(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ORG_ID)
);
```

Below is the Query and on average it takes around 90 Seconds to fetch the Required data and Optimizer is not using any Index I created, Data is fetched for last 5 days data which is around 40% of complete data. Please suggest some Optimizations and any Indexes if required

```
SELECT ED.ORG_ID, 
       ORG.ORG_IDENTITY, 
       ORG.ORG_NAME, 
       ED.CONFIG_KEY, 
       REPLACE(REPLACE(ED.COMPONENT_NAME,'-CURRENT',''),'-HISTORICAL','') AS COMP_NAME,
       DO.DOMAIN_IDENTITY,
       DO.DOMAIN_DISPLAY_NAME,
       GROUP_CONCAT(ED.STATUS ORDER BY ED.INSERTED_TIME DESC) AS ALL_STATUS 
FROM EVENT_DETAILS ED , 
     ORGANISATIONS ORG , 
     DOMAIN_KEYS DO   
WHERE UPDATE_DATE > '20191204' 
  AND ORG.ORG_ID = ED.ORG_ID 
  AND DO.DOMAIN_KEY=ED.CONFIG_KEY 
  AND DO.LOCATION_KEY <> 0 
GROUP BY ED.ORG_ID,
      ORG.ORG_IDENTITY, 
      ORG.ORG_NAME, 
      ED.CONFIG_KEY,
      DO.DOMAIN_IDENTITY,
      DO.DOMAIN_DISPLAY_NAME,
      COMP_NAME 
HAVING ALL_STATUS LIKE '0,0,0%';
```

Comment: Your query is somewhat invalid, because it is selecting the column `ED.COMPONENT_NAME`, which does not also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Regarding optimizations, without a `WHERE` clause there is not much you can do other than to possibly speed up the joins.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen COMP_NAME which is extracted from ED.COMPONENT_NAME is present in GROUP BY Clause.

Comment: Isn't this a dup of a Question on another forum?